# How to make Report Footer print at bottom of page

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I want the Report Footer to print at the bottom of the page rather than at the bottom of the end of the last line item of the report.

Also I'm formatting this for a paper that has a pre-printed grid on it and in order to make everything fit in the grid, I also have a Page Footer that's a couple inches high.  However, I need the Report Footer to print in the Page Footer area.

Answer (score 1):

There is no report footer in the Stimulsoft Reports.
There is a Report Summary where you could set the **Pring at Bottom** property.

Comment: Yes, I meant the Report Summary.  It is set to Print at Bottom, however it still prints above the Page Footer whereas I need it to print over the Page Footer area.  Or I need to somehow turn off the Page Footer on the last page.  I also tried setting the Print On property of the Page Footer to 'Except Last Page' but that didn't seem to help (I don't have anything in the Page Footer... it's just filler space because this is for a form with pre-printed stuff at the bottom.  Whether or not it actually 'prints' on the last page, it definitely still takes up space).

Comment: Use two Page Footers. Set Except Last Page and Onlt Last Page properties one and another.

Answer (score 0):

You should set **PrintOnAllPages = True** in the footer band

```
StiFooterBand footerBand = new StiFooterBand();
footerBand.Height = 0.5f;
footerBand.Name = "FooterBand";
footerBand.Border = new StiBorder(StiBorderSides.All, Color.Black, 1, StiPenStyle.Solid);
footerBand.PrintOnAllPages = true;            
page.Components.Add(footerBand);
```